# Give users who don't have sysadmin role the ability to use SSMS (or similar) to attach / detach databases from external source

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms, system-administration

I've searched high and low for how to do this. Let me give some background so we can avoid repeating the same old stuff.

At my company we sometimes receive hundreds of databases a month from external sources (i.e., we don't know what database users exist on these db's and never will).  I would like to have my analysts attach these databases -- using SSMS or another graphical tool -- WITHOUT giving them the sysadmin server role.

According to my research, the server roles dbcreator (and bulkadmin ???) are needed for attaching databases; however it appears that SSMS won't even show the Attach dialog box for users who don't have the sysadmin server role.

Although I'd prefer a set of permissions which allow users without sysadmin role to use SSMS or other GUI tools to attach / detach databases, I'd be interested in ANY way to do this.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a stored procedure that will attach or detach a database using `EXECUTE AS`, giving them execute rights on that, and asking them to learn how to execute a stored procedure instead of walking through the SSMS UI? If that's impossible, you could always write a quick windows forms app using C# or VB that calls the stored procedure...

Comment: Your second part -- writing a custom app that calls a stored procedure which uses EXECUTE AS -- is exactly something I had on my mind.  I don't want to do it because even though I think I could do it, I don't have lots of time to devote to such an project.  I'm also worried about writing something that can allow a user to select multiple files from a remote server.  Though I know there are components out there which can be used for this, I'm not a developer -- I'm a jack-of-all-trades IT administrator.  Any ideas regarding off-the-shelf tools for this sort of thing?

Comment: Not that I know of. But surely you can teach your users to execute a few lines of code?

Comment: :-)  Well, even I would hate to have to type in 20+ full path names.  Of course, if I modify my Attach-Database script (a PowerShell script I wrote some time ago) they could "simply" dump directory output of *.mdf to the script and it could call the stored proc.  <sigh> I was hoping not have to do any more scripting.

Comment: Ha ha, ok. So you don't want to have to type anything, and you don't want your users to have to type anything either. I guess you should re-tag with [tag:magic]. :-)